# How to read this multidimensional associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am fairly new to PHP and am doing some testing with a simple API.

The API returns an object of which the vardump looks like this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Curl-project\index.php:46:
array (size=1)
  'liveweer' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=49)
          'plaats' => string 'Venlo' (length=5)
          'temp' => string '9.5' (length=3)
          'gtemp' => string '7.9' (length=3)
          'samenv' => string 'Onbewolkt' (length=9)
          'lv' => string '88' (length=2)
          'windr' => string 'ZW' (length=2)
          'windms' => string '3' (length=1)
          'winds' => string '2' (length=1)
          'windk' => string '5.8' (length=3)
          'windkmh' => string '10.8' (length=4)
          'luchtd' => string '1001.9' (length=6)
```

How can I e.g. read the value "Venlo" that belongs to the key "plaats"?

Kind regards,

Hubert

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value by using related keys like this

```php
// this is your array
$array = [
    'liveweer' => [
        [
            'plaats' => 'Venlo',
            'temp' => '9.5',
            'gtemp' => '7.9',
            // so on...
        ]
    ]
];

// returns Venlo
$plaats = $array['liveweer'][0]['plaats'];
```